# What's the boy's name?

Tags: riddle, word, pattern

A German car, a place to stay, a country in the Northern hemisphere,
a beautiful girl, a unit prefix, a city in the Southern hemisphere, 
a green ranger, a rainy month, and a boy.

What's the boy's name?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is:

> Oscar

The reason is:

> The phonetic alphabet in alphabetic order.

A German car

> Golf

A place to stay

> Hotel

A country in the Northern hemisphere

> India

A beautiful girl

> Juliett

A unit prefix

> Kilo

A city in the Southern hemisphere

> Lima

A green ranger

> Mike

A rainy month

> November

A boy

> Oscar

Comment: could be charlie though

Comment: But it's also in alphabetic order @user345